# Update column in table2 based on select query which contains count() from table1 using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, subquery, aggregate-functions

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8id7L.png)

Need to update department table's dcount column based on number of employees working in each department from employee table's dno column.
Tried using
***update department set dcount=(select count(*) from employee INNER JOIN department ON employee.dno=department.dnumber group by dno);***
which gave an error : ***more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression***

Desired result is:

### **dname|dnumber|dcount

### Research|5|4

### Admin|4|3

Headquarters|1|1**

Need help please.
Thanks in advance.
Gruheeth

Comment: I recommend not to do it; just count them every time you need, otherwise you're just creating a maintenance headache for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery `(select count() ...)` returns several rows, one per employee, where postgres expect only one row from this subquery in order to update one row at a time in the `department` table. In this case, you case use a `cte` instead :

```
WITH list AS
(
select dno, count(*) AS dno_count
  from employee
 group by dno
)
update department AS d
   set dcount = l. dno_count 
  from  list AS l 
 where d.dnumber = l.dno ;
```